# How to access index of .map() method outside of it in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, indexing

I want to access the index number outside of that map method because I want to use that index conditionally to show other component like if that index is checked then the component will show but I can't figure out how to access that outside of that map method. I have googled it but couldn't find any proper solution of that.

**Here is my code!**

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import Clear from "./clear";
import Display from "./display";
import NoOfItems from "./noOfItems";

class MainPage extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: [
        {
          name: "",
          completed: false,
        },
      ],
      data: [],
      checkValue: false,
    };
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.setState({ name: e.target.value });
  };

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.setState({
      data: [...this.state.data, { name: this.state.name, completed: false }],
    });
    e.target.reset();
  };

  handleDelete = (index) => {
    const newList = [...this.state.data];
    newList.splice(index, 1);

    this.setState({ data: newList });
  };

  handleAllCheck = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  handleCheckChange = (index) => {
    let newData = [...this.state.data];
    newData[index].completed = !newData[index].completed;
    this.setState({ data: newData });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <h1 className="display-1 text-center" style={{ color: "#f7c6c6" }}>
          todos
        </h1>
        <form className="todo-form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label className="label" onClick={this.handleAllCheck}>
            ^
          </label>
          <input
            autoFocus
            type="text"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            className="new-todo shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 bg-white"
            placeholder="What needs to be done?"
          />
          <ul className="list-group">
            {this.state.data.map((data, index) => {
              return (
                <div key={"todo-" + index} className="div-list">
                  <input
                    className="check"
                    onChange={() => this.handleCheckChange(index)}
                    type="checkbox"
                    style={{
                      cursor: "pointer",
                    }}
                    defaultChecked={this.state.data.completed}
                  />
                  <li
                    className="list-group-item disabled w-50 p-3 mx-auto"
                    style={{
                      textDecoration:
                        this.state.data[index].completed && "line-through",
                    }}
                  >
                    {data.name}
                  </li>
                  <button
                    onClick={() => this.handleDelete(index)}
                    type="button"
                    className="close"
                    aria-label="Close"
                  >
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                  </button>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </ul>
          {this.state.data.length > 0 && <Display />}
          {this.state.data.length > 0 && (
            <NoOfItems noOfTodos={this.state.data.length} />
          )}
          {this.state.data.completed && <Clear />}
        </form>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default MainPage;
```

Just ignore the rest and see the map method and its index. At the end of the code I have used `this.state.data.completed` at this point I want to use the index like this `this.state.data[index].completed` but its saying invalid declaration of Index. Please help me I am stuck!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: which component are you talking about  in this comment ? ``` if that index is checked then the component will show```

Comment: Create your `div` array before your `return (<Fragment></Fragment>)` statement.
That way you'll be able to store the `index` in a variable for example

Comment: this.state.data[index] is similar to data variable in map function callback, i can not get question

Comment: On div key try to modify like this ``todo-${index}``

Comment: Are you wanting all to be completed before showing `<Clear/>`? Not really clear what higher level problem you are trying to solve

Comment: @MohammadFaisal see that in text Decoration I have used index so like this I want to display Clear component

Comment: @DmitryReutov Basically I just want to get that index number to use outside of the map method

Comment: There is nothing to index outside the map function. This is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) which means you need to explain the higher level problem you are actually trying to solve

Comment: @charlietfl the `<Clear />` component contains a button and I want to display it when the user check the checkBox and that checkbox contains Boolean state "completed" and it has index to identify that which field is completed

Comment: So one clear per item? If so why wouldn't it be rendered in the map()? Still not explaining this well

Comment: @charlietfl no... this App contain only one clear button and its up to the user that how many field he will check and the clear button will delete all the checked field in one go

Comment: OK...so you want it to show if any items are completed then I think? `{this.state.data.some(({completed})=> completed) && <Clear/>}` would do that

Comment: then why not to do this: ```{ this.state.data.some(d => d.completed) && <Clear /> }``` ???

Comment: @charlietfl you still didn't get it I am trying to say that user will check the checkbox telling that this task is completed now when the user checked it a button should appear and on clicking this button it will remove all the checked/completed task/field

Comment: I'm getting it.... the above will show the button which is all you asked so far. You need to do more to your `<Clear/>` component to do the rest. We have no idea what that component looks like and you don't show passing any props into it

Comment: Ohh my bad @charlietfl..the above code is working thanks :)

Comment: So what did we learn here? explain what you are actually trying to accomplish not with broken code but with a properly detailed written explanation and we would have solved this very quickly. Showing the code you tried is proper...what was missing was the higher level problem statement. Read that XY problem link thoroughly to understand better

Comment: Okay will do  that for sure